# Can a script have 2 Update methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my update function. I have a class called `HydraBehaviour` for my Hydra Enemy in my game. And the `HydraBehaviour` inherits from the `EnemyBehaviourClass` which is a class with a update method to `ChasePlay();` and `StopChasingPlayer();`.

In my Hydra class I want to create the attack System, because not all Enemies will have the same time attacking style. And so my problem is that I can't use the update method in Hydra Class, because it's already used in the `EnemyBehaviourClass`. So I'm forced to use Fixed Update but that's not the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have an update function in your HydraBehaviour and call the update function in EnemyBehaviourClass.

```
public class HydraBehaviour : EnemyBehaviourClass
{
    void Update()
    {
        base.Update();

        // Your Hydra specific code goes here
    }
}
```

Just make sure your Update function in EnemyBehaviourClass is either **public** or **protected**. This will not work if the function is private.